# OSX. Document & Window Controller design. How to interact with model

Tags: macos, cocoa, controller

I am working on a personal OS X App, using Cocoa, and I have some trouble designing the interaction between the Document and its Window Controller.

This is the summary of what I have so far:

- A **Document** (NSDocument subclass), which owns the "model data", and is in charge of loading, saving the data from/to files, etc.
- A **Window Controller** (NSWindowController subclass), attached to the Document, which creates the Window, and takes care that the "model data" is properly displayed to the user.

Now, my question:

How the Window Controller and the Document interact? More specifically: when an event happens in the view (e.g. the user enters some data), how the Window Controller reaches the Model? I see two options:

1. The Window Controller takes care of updating the data in the Model. This seems straightforward, but creates some caos in how the Model is accessed, since the Document is the one that should manage the Model Data.
2. The Window Controller sends a request to the Document, and the Document takes care of updating the model. This keeps things more clear conceptually, but its implementation feels weird: Window Controller will call Document's "applyChange:" method, and Document will perform an "applyChange:" on the Model; I would be duplicating virtually everything going from the View to the Model, since the Document would act as a facade for the Model, and the Window Controller would act as a facade of the Document... Feels like too many facades!

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

Subclass of NSDocument is is a model controller (Thanks for correcting me).
 
More on that:[NSDocument from design perspective](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Designing/Designing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH2-SW3) is an object in memory that owns and manages the document data.

[image]

To reach your document from window controller simply call [@selector(document)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindowController/document)

```
[self document]; //within windowController subclass
```

Design:

You follow the MVC pattern and other design patterns (mostly delegates and notifications). 
Take a look at [Lister app](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/resources/sample-code/). If you don't have access I have uploaded it to [github](https://github.com/xhruso00/listeraproductivityapp)
Also a wonderful example (behind wall) is ShapeArt app DEMO during WWDC 2013 (Bringing Your iOS Apps to OS X).

Maybe your question is more suitable to move to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Yes. I know this. My question is not about how to reach the document. What I want to know is which is the most convenient strategy to keep the model updated. It's just a design matter.

Comment: Also, actually it's not true that subclass of NSDocument is the model. The model is owned and managed by an NSDocument subclass; the NSDocument is a "model controller", but not the model itself.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. If you want to recreate the ShapeArt app together just mail me.

Comment: I have just found a 3rd option: binding. You just link your NSObjectController or other property to "Applications" keypath: mainWindow.windowController.document.identifier http://imgur.com/HkQGy9A